# toString use in Java

Tags: java, tostring

I have a query about toString() in Java, when I create a toString method, I was taught to do, for example:

```
  public String toString(){

    return....
  }
```

I am wondering can I do it as a no return value method like, for example:

```
  public void toString(){

  System.out.println(....);
  }
```

Comment: A proper Java program rarely uses the console to show strings to the user. That is 95% class study only... Why would it have a use? You should rather call that method "print()" or somethign else.

Comment: @ppeterka,thanks for your reply, well, the toString() here is to print the object with its attributes, so I do not need to call the method in my main() class to print the value, for instance, without toString(), I have to do object.getName()+object.getAge()+object.getGender()...something like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you cannot. You end up with a compile time error. `The return type is incompatible`, Since it is inherited from  `Object#toString()`

You can like

```
public void toMyString(){

 }
```

Since it new instance method belongs to current class:)

Edit (specific scenario's):

**Type `void`:**

```
public void printOneMessage(){
System.out.println("printed .That's it");
}
```

**Type `return`:**

```
public boolean printOneMessageAndLetMeknow(){
 // some  logic weather to print or not
 System.out.println("printed .That's it");

 return true;
}
```

Another for `return`

```
public MyObjectType setSomeThingToObjectAndGiveMeBack(MyObjectType receiveObj){
  receiveObj.setSomeProperty(someVal);

 return receiveObj; //returning modified
}
```

These are just for example's.

Comment: Oh thank you Suresh, another question, generally speaking, I know what the difference between returned value method and void method, but how should I decide which one to use in specific scenario?

Comment: Thank you for your example, much appreciated, so the method with return value can also have a function for updating things, can I understand it like this?

Comment: Depends ..:)  not nessesarily ..if you are writing a method to modify a object and want to receive that back ..then yes.

Answer (score 2):

The `toString()` method in your class is overriding the `toString()` method of its parent class, so no, you cannot change the return type of an overriding method to something that does not inherit from the original return type.

Answer (score 2):

`String toString()` is inherited from the `Object` class. Defining a `void toString()` would throw a compile time error because it's an **illegal** override since the method signatures match but the return types are not compatible (same or co-variant).

---

Even if you don't provide a `toString()` implementation for a class you can still invoke `toString()` on its object. That's because every class by default extends `Object` and inherits the base implementation of `toString()` (among other things) from it.

When you define a `toString()` method of your own you're basically doing what's known in OOPs as an *method override* i.e. providing your own method implementation that supersedes the one that you inherit from any of your parent classes.

A **legal** method override requires the method signature to match the one you're trying to override as well as stipulates that the return types must either be same or co-variant i.e. your type must be assignable to the original return type.

Comment: Hi Ravi, what do you mean it is inherited from the object class, I normally use String toString() in the superclass, then it will print all the objects in the main() method

Answer (score 0):

You have to use return for any methods of the type int, String, and boolean. If it is a void method, then you don't need to use return.